Guacamole RDP “Connection failed (server unreachable)”
I am trying to run Guacamole and guacd using Docker but facing below issues while connecting a remote desktop
So far I have done a Docker setup of Guacamole and guacd which seems to be running without errors.
In Guacamole web interface had created an RDP connection with the following configuration;
Hostname: remote desktop ip
Port: 3389
Error log when trying to connect :
guacamole_compose  | Exception in thread "Thread-17" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Message will not be sent because the WebSocket session has been closed
guacamole_compose  |    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:449)
guacamole_compose  |    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:307)
guacamole_compose  |    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:249)
guacamole_compose  |    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:191)
guacamole_compose  |    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendText(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:36)
guacamole_compose  |    at org.apache.guacamole.websocket.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.sendInstruction(GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.java:152)
guacamole_compose  | 09:22:40.066 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  o.a.g.tunnel.TunnelRequestService - User "TigerIT" connected to connection "3".
guacamole_compose  | 09:22:45.177 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  o.a.g.tunnel.TunnelRequestService - User "TigerIT" disconnected from connection "3". Duration: 5109 milliseconds
guacamole_compose  | 09:22:48.277 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  o.a.g.r.auth.AuthenticationService - User "TigerIT" successfully authenticated from 172.18.0.1.
guacamole_compose  | 09:23:56.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  o.a.g.tunnel.TunnelRequestService - User "TigerIT" connected to connection "3".
guacamole_compose  | 09:24:12.077 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  o.a.g.tunnel.TunnelRequestService - User "TigerIT" disconnected from connection "3". Duration: 15337 milliseconds
guacamole_compose  | 09:56:49.068 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] INFO  o.a.g.tunnel.TunnelRequestService - User "TigerIT" disconnected from connection "3". Duration: 15340 milliseconds


This is the docker compose file
version: '3.8'

networks:
  guacnetwork_compose:
    driver: bridge

services:
  guacd:
    container_name: guacd_compose
    image: guacamole/guacd
    networks:
      - guacnetwork_compose
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./drive:/drive:rw
      - ./record:/record:rw

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_guacamole_compose
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/guacamole
      POSTGRES_DB: guacamole_db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '1234'
      POSTGRES_USER: guacamole_user
    networks:
      - guacnetwork_compose
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:z
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z

  guacamole:
    container_name: guacamole_compose
    image: guacamole/guacamole
    depends_on:
      - guacd
      - postgres
    environment:
      GUACD_HOSTNAME: guacd
      POSTGRES_DATABASE: guacamole_db
      POSTGRES_HOSTNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '1234'
      POSTGRES_USER: guacamole_user
    networks:
      - guacnetwork_compose
    volumes:
      - ./record:/record:rw
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

Do I need to install any client to get connected with remote desktop ??
